# Use of python nmap calls in pyinstaller executable for windows

Tags: python, windows, executable, nmap

I'd like to replace our ping/ARP code which does IP address resolution with nmap calls.

We build an executable file for device testing using Python 3.7 with Pyinstaller to distribute to multiple (20 - 30) PCs running Windows 10 in several geographies.

BUT, from what I understand, we will need to have the nmap windows library code installed on each PC: the python-pip package is only the interface to manipulation interfaces, and does not contain the actual nmap library code. I discovered this during initial investigation on my test PC.

Am I correct on this? If so, is there an additional python package I could install and build into the exe file that would handle the nmap library calls? Or some other work-around or suggestion?

Hope this makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. I'm actually looking into this as well. All I found that you [can OEM](https://nmap.org/oem/) `nmap` into your binary, but that's not free. Will cost you from $50k to $100k.